# get xts objects from within an environment

Tags: r, get, environment, xts, quantmod

I have stored xts objects inside an environment. Can I subset these objects while they are stored in an environment, i.e. act upon them "in-place"? Can I extract these objects by referring to their *colname*?

Below an example of what I'm getting at.

```
# environment in which to store data 
data <- new.env()

# Set data tickers of interest
tickers <- c("FEDFUNDS", "GDPPOT", "DGS10")

# import data from FRED database
library("quantmod")
dta <- getSymbols( tickers
  , src = "FRED"
  , env = data
  , adjust = TRUE
)
```

This, however, downloads the entire dataset. Now, I want to discard some data, save it, use it (e.g. plot it). I want to keep the data within this date range:

```
# set dates of interest
date.start <- "2012-01-01"
date.end <- "2012-12-31"
```

I have two distinct objectives.

1. to subset all of the data inside of the environment (either
   acting in-place or creating a new environment and overwriting the
   old environment with it).
2. to take only some tickers of my choosing and to subset those,
       say FEDFUNDS and DGS10, and afterwards save them in a new
       environment. I also want to preserve the xts-ness of these objects, so I can conveniently plot them together or separately.

Here are some things I did manage to do:

```
# extract and subset a single xts object 
dtx1 <- data$FEDFUNDS
dtx1 <- dtx1[paste(date.start,date.end,sep="/")]
```

The drawback of this approach is that I need to type FEDFUNDS explicitly after data$. But I'd like to work from a prespecified list of tickers, e.g.

```
tickers2 <- c("FEDFUNDS", "DGS10")
```

I have got one step closer to being systematic by combining the function *get* with the function *lapply*

```
# extract xts objects as a list
dtxl <- lapply(tickers, get, envir = data)
```

But this returns a list. And I'm not sure how to conveniently work with this list to subset the data, plot it, etc. How do I refer to, say, DGS10 or the pair of tickers in tickers2?

I very much wanted to write something like **data$tickers[1]** or **data$tickers[[1]]** but that didn't work. I also tried **paste0('data','$',tickers[1])** and variations of it with or without quotes. At any rate, I believe that the order of the data inside an environment is not systematic, so I'd really prefer to use the ticker's name rather than its index, something like **data$tickers[colnames = FEDFUNDS]** None of the attempts in this paragraph have worked.

If my question is unclear, I apologize, but please do request clarification. And thanks for your attention!

**EDIT: Subsetting**

I've received some fantastic suggestions. **GSee**'s answer has several very useful tricks. Here's how to subset the xts objects to within a date interval of interest:

```
dates <- paste(date.start, date.end, sep="/")
as.environment(eapply(data, "[", dates))
```

Comment: `with` can be useful when working with environments. `with(data, FEDFUNDS[paste(date.start, date.end, sep="/")])`

Comment: Re: your last paragraph, are you looking for `get(tickers[1], pos=data)`?

Comment: Thanks Gsee. I had tried to use the first construct, but I hadn't managed to get it to work with a vector of tickers. I'll need to look into the second approach, I don't know how to use `pos`. But you've given me some excellent methods in your answer below anyhow. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will subset every object in an environment, and return an environment with the subsetted data:

```
data2 <- as.environment(eapply(data, "[", paste(date.start, date.end, sep="/")))
```

You can do basically the same thing for your second question.  Just, name the components of the list that `lapply` returns by wrapping it with `setNames`, then coerce to an environment:

```
data3 <- as.environment(setNames(lapply(tickers, get, envir = data), tickers))
```

Or, better yet, use `mget` so that you don't have to use `lapply` or `setNames`

```
data3 <- as.environment(mget(tickers, envir = data))
```

---

Alternatively I actually have a couple convenience functions in [`qmao`](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1113) designed specifically for this:  [`gaa`](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/qmao/R/gaa.R?view=markup&root=twsinstrument) stands for "get, apply, assign" and [`gsa`](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/qmao/R/gsa.R?view=markup&root=twsinstrument) stands for "get, subset, assign".

To, get data for some tickers, subset the data, and then assign into an environment

```
gsa(tickers, subset=paste(date.start, date.end, sep="/"), env=data, 
    store.to=globalenv())
```

`gaa` lets you apply any function to each object before saving in the same or different environment.

Comment: +1 for the convenience functions in `qmao`. I've just started exploring qmao and did spend some time trying to use `do.call.rbind`, but the environment was causing me problems. `gaa` and `gsa` are perfect: it's like mind-reading magic. I'm now going to sit down and actually read the `qmao` manual! ;-)

Comment: I had come across `as.environment` but I was missing `setNames` and also how to use `eapply` with the square bracket. Will investigate these now. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT, see edit for an alternative to using `setNames`.  Here's another alternative: `as.environment(sapply(tickers, get, envir = data, simplify=FALSE))`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you want smth like this:

```
dtxl = do.call(cbind, sapply(tickers2,
           function(ticker) get(ticker, env=data)[paste(date.start,date.end,sep="/")])
       )
```

Comment: Thanks eddi. At present this is giving me the following error message: `Error in do.call(cbind, sapply(tickers2, function(ticker) get(ticker, : second argument must be a list`. I tried to wrap the second argument with as.list, but that obviously isn't enough.

Comment: @PatrickT, sounds like `sapply` is not returning a list (one of the reasons to be very careful about when and how you use `sapply`).  Try adding the argument `simplify=FALSE`, or just use `lapply` instead of `sapply`.  This answer is going to return a single `xts` with many columns.