# Processing multiple quant mod stock tickers in parallel in R

Tags: r, zoo, quantmod, stockquotes, env

I might not explain my questions clear in the title, apologize.
Here is the question with the code, it will be clearer,

```
library(zoo);library(quantmod)
stockData <- new.env()#Make a new environment for quantmod to store data in
startDate = as.Date("2006-12-29") #Specify period of time we are interested in
endDate = as.Date("2012-12-31")
monthlyStartDate = as.Date("2007-01-01")

# tickers <- c("AAPL","GOOG", "IBM")
tickers <- c("AAPL","GOOG", "IBM", "MSFT", "INTC", "YHOO", "F", "GS", "UL") 
# The tickers vector could be even larger, i.e.  50 stocks

stockData$AAPL.ret=diff(log(stockData$AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted)) # Compute log returns
stockData$GOOG.ret=diff(log(stockData$GOOG$GOOG.Adjusted)) # Compute log returns
stockData$IBM.ret=diff(log(stockData$IBM$IBM.Adjusted)) # Compute log returns
head(stockData$GOOG.ret)
head(stockData$GOOG$GOOG.Adjusted)

AAPLmonthly<-aggregate.zoo(stockData$AAPL.ret[2:nrow(stockData$AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted),],as.yearmon,sum)
GOOGmonthly<-aggregate.zoo(stockData$GOOG.ret[2:nrow(stockData$GOOG$GOOG.Adjusted),],as.yearmon,sum)
IBMmonthly<-aggregate.zoo(stockData$IBM.ret[2:nrow(stockData$IBM$IBM.Adjusted),],as.yearmon,sum)


head(AAPLmonthly)
stockret = cbind(AAPLmonthly, GOOGmonthly, IBMmonthly)
head(stockret)
```

The above code only used 3 `tickers` as an example, I want to know how to do a `loop` in R to make my whole vector of tickers into the `stockret` `zoo` object, could anybody help me? Much appreciated.

I am learning environment, just learnt the function is an closure, including the body, arguments and its environment, but I didn't know we could new an environment. So I got stuck here, `stockData$AAPL.ret` how do I put the `stockData$` in front of my each element while doing a loop to assign values? Should I use `"["` to do this?
Besides, if I use the `assign` function to do this,  in the code

```
stockData$AAPL.ret=diff(log(stockData$AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted)) # Compute log returns
```

how to do this, I'm just confused about how to make this `stockData$AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted` a more general argument in my `assign` function, any example would be much appreciated!

Comment: You seem to be missing the call to get the ticker data into stockData - without this it's not clear what the structure of the data you are using is.  Please provide that and/or an example of the data you are processing.

Comment: What assign function?

Comment: yearmon is a function in the Zoo package - you should probably put `library(zoo)` at the start of your code.

Comment: sort of related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980985/get-xts-objects-from-within-an-environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get` to get data from an environment and `assign` to assign data to a symbol in an environment.

```
library(quantmod)
stockData <- new.env()
tickers <- c("AAPL","GOOG", "IBM", "MSFT", "INTC", "YHOO", "F", "GS", "UL") 
getSymbols(tickers, src="yahoo", env=stockData)

for (tick in tickers) {
  x <- get(tick, pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment
  x$ret <- diff(log(Ad(x)))      # add a column with returns
  assign(tick, x, pos=stockData) # assign back into stockData environment
  assign(paste0(tick, "monthly"), 
         apply.monthly(x, sum, na.rm=TRUE), 
         pos=stockData) # calc monthly sum and assign in stockData environment
}
```

Or, your could use eapply to apply a function to every object in the environment
The result will be a list that you can coerce back into an environment

```
stockData <- as.environment(eapply(stockData, function(x) {
  x$ret <- diff(log(Ad(x)))
  x
}))
```

Or you could create a list of only the returns, then loop over that
to calculate the monthly sums

```
R <- eapply(stockData, function(x) diff(log(Ad(x))))
monthly <- lapply(R, apply.monthly, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

You can merge the results into a single object like this

```
do.call(merge, R)
do.call(merge, monthly)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Assignment outside the local scope

Firstly, function bodies operate in a child scope, even when assigning to variables declared in the global or containing scope.

R has a special operator `<<-` for setting variables in parent scopes (environments).  See `?assignOps` for details.

For example:

```
a <- 1
(function(){ a <- a + 1 })()
```

A new `a` is created in the local scope at the point of assignment, so the internal value goes to 2, but the global remains 1.

```
a <- 1
(function(){ a <<- a + 1 })()
```

Using the `<<-` assignment operator searches the parent environments in turn and finds our global a.  Global A gets the value 2 in this case.

### Functional Programming

In R, functional programming is encouraged.  See my other answer on quantmod for how you might approach this with time series.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for `lapply` and `do.call` for me, for instance (untested)

```
tickers <- c("AAPL","GOOG", "IBM")

as_monthly <- function(sym) {
    log_returns <- diff(log(stockdata[[sym]][[paste(sym, "Adjusted", sep=".")]]))
    aggregate(log_returns[2:nrow(log_returns),], as.yearmon, sum)
}

assign("stockret", do.call(cbind, lapply(tickers, as_monthly)), envir=stockdata)
```

It is not clear from your question how you populate the `stockdata` environment, though.

Comment: Thanks, the original assignment only used the 3 tickers as an example, and `stockData` was created by the professor. I think `stockData` is for better organizing the stock data, to store all the stock data in this environment? Would you tell me how to put the environment in front of the stock data here?

Comment: If your question is how to modify a list element within an environment, my guess is that you have to replace the complete list in the environment. That is, `newval <- ...; assign("AAPL", newval, envir=stockdata)`. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Quantmod` has the unusual behavior that it adds its results to the enclosing environment.

```
> getSymbols(c("AAPL","ORCL"))
[1] "AAPL" "ORCL"
```

returns the list of symbols it retrieves, but has the *side effect* that it assigns the results into the caller's environment:

```
ls()
[1] "AAPL" "ORCL"

> nrow(AAPL)
1774
> class(AAPL)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

For writing scripts, this can be messy, so as the OP suggests it can be a good idea to create a dedicated environment for this:

```
> stocks <- new.env()
> getSymbols(c("AAPL","ORCL"),stocks)
> ls(stocks)
[1] "AAPL" "ORCL"
```

This approach prevents name collisions, and allows the returned results to be processed as a group.  Now we have collected the data together, it's more convenient to replace the environment with a more traditional data structure, for instance, have each ticker be a list element:

```
> stocksL <- as.list(stocks)
```

Now we can use Map or Lapply effectively.

```
> Map(function() { "do something " }, stocksL)
```

Note that since `getSymbols` prefixes the column names with the ticker name, it would be useful to clean that off:

```
> stocksL2 <- Map(function(x) {names(x)<-gsub(".*\\.","",names(x));x}, stocksL)
```

Now we can reprocess it

```
> adj <- Map(function(x) {diff(log(x$Adjusted))}, stocksL2)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question. The OP didn't even mention `getSymbols`

Comment: He surely intended to.  Without that vital clue (that getSymbols main value is for its side effect - writing to an environment) the question makes little sense.

Comment: @GSee hmm, I see you mention getSymbols in your reply?  care to comment?

Comment: I thought the Q was about how to assign in an environment, not about how `getSymbols` works, since it looks like the OP already knows how `getSymbols` works.  I guess you've edited your Answer to make it slightly more relevant since my comment.

Comment: @GSee @Alex Brown Thank you all for pointing out my mistakes. I did left over part of the code, `getSymbols`, etc. I'll further check these when I get back home, appreciated! Learnt a lot from all you.